# I'm having trouble understanding this code

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm new to python and trying to learn by practicing on hackerrank. I'm not understanding this list concept. This is the problem

**Input Format:**

The first line contains an integer, , the number of students. 
The  subsequent lines describe each student over  lines; the first line contains a student's name, and the second line contains their grade.

**Constraints**

There will always be one or more students having the second lowest grade.

**Output Format:**

Print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade in Physics; if there are multiple students, order their names alphabetically and print each one on a new line.

**Sample Input 0:**

```
5

Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

**Sample Output 0:**

```
Berry

Harry
```

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function
score_list = {}
for _ in range(input()):
    name = raw_input()
    score = float(raw_input())
    if score in score_list:
        score_list[score].append(name)
    else:
        score_list[score] = [name]
new_list = []
for i in score_list:
     new_list.append([i, score_list[i]])
new_list.sort()
result = new_list[1][1]
result.sort()
print (*result, sep = "\n")
```

I'm not able to understand the "in" function here, doesn't `in` check for a value in the list, and so isn't `score_list` empty?

Comment: is this python2 or python3?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Its python 3, look at the print function

Comment: @Wimanicesir Python2 (`raw_input`). The print function comes from the import.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use tuples in a list, then sort by score, which is in the tuple? Also, `score_list[score].append(name)`, what does that do? Append strings?

Comment: @dustin-we The type of `score_list[score]` is 'list', `score_list[score].append(name)` will append to that list.

Comment: @KshitijSaxena My bad, I think I read over that part too quickly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added comments in the code for better understanding, hope this helps.

```
from __future__ import print_function
# Create an empty dict
score_list = {}
# Take a number input and run this loop that many times
for _ in range(input()):
    name = raw_input()
    score = float(raw_input())
    # if value of score is an existing key in dict, add name to the value of that key
    if score in score_list:
        score_list[score].append(name)
    else:
        # Else create a key with score value and initiate the value with a list
        score_list[score] = [name]
new_list = []
for i in score_list:
     new_list.append([i, score_list[i]])
new_list.sort()
result = new_list[1][1]
result.sort()
print (*result, sep = "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time the dictionary is empty, but the second time it isn't. I added comment on every line.

```
# Import
from __future__ import print_function
# Create a new dictionary to save the scores
score_list = {}
# For every input, do something
for _ in range(input()):
    # Grab the name of the current user
    name = raw_input()
    # Grab the score of the current
    score = float(raw_input())
    # If the score is already in the list,
    # append the name to that score
    if score in score_list:
        score_list[score].append(name)
    # Else add the new score and name to the list
    else:
        score_list[score] = [name]
# Create a new list
new_list = []
# Copy score list into the new list
for i in score_list:
     new_list.append([i, score_list[i]])
# Sort on score value
new_list.sort()
# Return the second highest score
result = new_list[1][1]
# Sort the names of the result
result.sort()
# Print it
print (*result, sep = "\n")
```